# Sum values from a table in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sum a particular column from my table using just a loop. There are two tables: `cars` and `uteams`. I want to calculate the total speed from `cars` for all users that are in the team.

Here is what I've tried:

```
function tspeed($team)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `uteams` WHERE tid='$tid'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $veh = get_uacar($row['uid']);
        $speed = get_tspeed($row['uid']);
        echo '' . $speed . '';
    }
}
```

`get_tspeed($row['uid'])` gets the speed for one user.

`$veh = get_uacar($row['uid']);` gets the car.

My output is

> 100 150 120

However, I want to output the sum of the values. How can I do this?

Comment: if any of these answers helped kindly pick an answer by clicking that checkmark on the left side of the answer you like http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting each speed is because you have `echo $speed` inside your while loop.

So far you haven't set a value for $speed and at the moment it gets erased with each loop. Plus you aren't adding anything. This may help:

```
$speed = 0;
$sqle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uteams WHERE tid='$tid'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqle)) {
   $veh = get_uacar($row['uid']);
   $speed += get_tspeed($row['uid']);
}
echo $speed;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a variable and keep adding to it at each iteration:

```
$total_speed = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqle)) {
    $veh = get_uacar($row['uid']);
    $speed = get_tspeed($row['uid']);
    $total_speed += $speed;        // ADD SPEED TO TOTAL
    echo '' . $speed . '';
}

echo "Total Speed: " . $total_speed;
```